# Purpose of laminations crossing squirrel cage induction motor rotor bars

Tags: induction-motor

Below is a squirrel cage induction motor's rotor and on the left shows only the shorted aluminum rotor bars; and on the right it shows the lamination disks are added to the rotor.

[image]

As far as I know the rotor can still rotate(as on the left) without those laminations. Those shorted bars are actually the structure which creates rotation. They form coils and pass currents and hence create torque and rotation ect.

But why are these limitations(on the right side) needed in construction of the rotor?

Comment: I always thought those were just for mechanical support.

Comment: Oh you mean to be able use bearings for the shaft?

Comment: @user16307 Rotor core is a common constructional feature for all rotating machines. There are slots in the rotor core in which each of the bars is inserted and then shorted from the outside. The core is mounted on the shaft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An induction motor is basically a regular power transformer but the secondary is "shorted" and is allowed to rotate. Would you expect good efficiency if you had big air gaps in a regular power transformer? Maybe you don't know how power transformers work?

The bottom line with power transformers is that you want the primary magnetism (stator) coupled to the secondary winding (rotor) as much as possible and you therefore avoid large air gaps that would bypass the secondary winding.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic flux must pass through the rotor. The rotor conductors are surrounded by iron so that magnetic flux has an easy path to flow. Some other material could be used to support the rotor cage and connect it to the shaft, but iron is more effective. Without iron a higher magnetomotive force would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Laminations (usually thin silicon steel 0.2 to 0.7 mm) are used to reduce eddy current losses